# extra option causing button to move up and down

Tags: html, css, angular

How do you position a button so it stays fixed?

I have an Angular app and when the 3rd option is displayed for a multiple choice, the next and back buttons move down.

Some of the questions only have 2 options and some have 3.

Is there a way to make it so that the buttons stay at one position? I tried using `position` property in css and `margin-bottom`, but no luck.

**2 Options**
[image: 2 Options]

**3 Options**
[image: 3 Options]

**CSS**

```
button {
  background-color: #004273;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #93b9dd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.buttons2 {
  width:48%;
  float: right;
}

.buttons1 {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2 style="color: white;" align="center">{{statement}}</h2>
<h2 style="color: white;" align="center">{{question}}</h2>
<div class="radio-{{questionType}} col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4">
  <div class="form-check">
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" class="options">
      <mat-radio-button value="{{radio1}}">{{radio1}}</mat-radio-button> <br>
      <mat-radio-button value="{{radio2}}">{{radio2}}</mat-radio-button> <br>
      <span *ngIf="radio3">
        <mat-radio-button value="{{radio3}}">
          {{radio3}} 
        </mat-radio-button>
      </span>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" style="padding-top: 2%;">
    <button *ngIf="state !== 1; else disabled_btn" class="buttons1 btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickedBack.emit(selectedValue)">BACK</button>
    <ng-template #disabled_btn>
      <button class="buttons1 btn" (click)="onClickedBack.emit(selectedValue)" disabled>BACK</button>
    </ng-template>
    <button class="buttons2 btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickedNext.emit(selectedValue)">NEXT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:nth-child()` CSS selector to modify the behavior of the options.

```
.options > :nth-child(3) {
  height: 0;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

The above selects the 3rd direct child of `.options` class element group, removes the height, but ensures that it still shows. You may have to adjust this based on other CSS.